# Como enviar file o image por ajax y recibirlo en webservice asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net, webservice

Buenas soy nuevo en esto de la programación y he estado buscando información por Internet ya dos días y no encuentro la solución, quisiera  que me ayuden con este código, ya que estoy intentando enviar una imagen vía ajax al servidor asp.net,  y que me guarde la imagen en disco y obtener la ruta para luego guardarlo en una base de datos,sin utilizar MVC.

`Lado del cliente:

    Cargar Imagen

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#btnCargar").click(function () {
        var form_data = new FormData();

        form_data.append("archivo", $('#fileEjemplo')[0].files[0]);

               //  formData.append("file", file);
        $.ajax({
            url: '<%=ResolveUrl("bproducto.aspx/subirarchivos")%>',
            type: 'POST',
            data: form_data,
           // cache: false,
            processData: false, // Don't process the files
            contentType: false, // Set content type to false as jQuery will tell the server its a query string request
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',

            success: function (response) {
                var res = response.d;
                console.log(res);


            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                var err = eval("(" + XMLHttpRequest.responseText + ")");
                alert("ojo" + err.Message)
                console.log("Ajax Error!");
            }
        });

    });


     </script>
```

lado del servidor [WebMethod]

```
    public static  string subirarchivos(HttpPostedFileBase archivo){

?????????  //no sé cómo recibirlo
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Si se agrega el archivo en el multipart de la llamada HTTP "debería" poder leerse en el `Request.Files`

Por ello prueba con:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string SubirArchivos(){
    var archivo = Request.Files["archivo"];
}
```

Comment: y eso como por qué o para qué?

Comment: @RuslanLópezCarro si agrega el archivo en el multipart de la llamada HTTP "debería" poder leerse en el Request.Files

Comment: perfecto, lo agrego a la respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Pues en el endpoint del back diciendole que los datos vienen de `FromForm` como:

```
 public static string subirArchivo([FromForm] LaClaseQueSea inputData){
 }
```

Y la clase que lleva los datos del endpoint:

```
 public class LaClaseQueSea
 {
     public IFormFile archivo { get; set; }
 }
```

Si el form_data que envias tiene otras propiedades pues los agregarías a "LaClaseQueSea"